# Can I build a .Net Core 3.0 WPF project for ARM?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, arm

Can I build a .Net Core 3.0 WPF project for ARM?

When trying to build I get the errors

error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-arm'.
error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win10-arm'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, found the answer myself: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/1817

So not supported. Any info on if (when) it ever will be supported is still very welcome though.